# PHP, can ? store string from password_hash as primary key in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a string config like : "healtheworld"

And I convert it using password hash like this

```
password_hash($string, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

and then I store it on db, inside field >> "token" (Primary key)

I can do it ?

if I can, if the string of password_hash generated again, will have a chance same result on database before ?

Comment: In short, yes, it should be fine. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162679/bcrypt-hash-as-database-table-id/162737

Comment: `password_hash("healtheworld", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` will generate a different hash each time it's been used this is because to counter rainbow tables.. You need to use `password_verify("healtheworld", $hash)` to verify the database stored hash.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Yes, you can. But obviously there will be no "autoincrement", which means you'll have to provide the key when inserting data.
Side note: You could have used a UNIQUE key as well

Comment: But the hash will be different if using `password_hash()` @CD001 even if the password is [the same](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) paragraph starting with "Michael changed his username but his password is amazingly familiar:"

Comment: @JayBlanchard - that occurred to me approx. 0.5 seconds after writing the comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because a hashed password completed with `password_hash()` generates a unique hash each time you can use the generated hash as the primary key in a table. Just make sure the column is 60 or more characters long.

Comment: oh god, you know what i mean :)... i think My english really bad :)
Thank you sir